# How to remap thinkpad Keyboard(F11) and Favorites(F12) keys?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, thinkpad

On my Thinkpad T480s, the function keys all have icons on them for volume control, brightness, etc. The F11 and F12 keys have a keyboard and favorites icon, but those don't appear to do anything in Ubuntu. I'd like to remap those keys to different functions (for example, show the Activities menu / all open windows). However, I can't remap these keys as normal in keyboard shortcuts, those icon keys don't register when trying to create a shortcut.

How can I remap these keys? I saw [this suggestion](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/ab0jk7/how_to_remap_favorite_f12_key_to_launch_an_app_on/) for debian. Is that the proper solution for Ubuntu 18.04 or is there a better way?

Thanks!